# Update post by specific id

Tags: php, wordpress

I am struggeling with the following functionality. I would like to update a post that has the `currentUserName` in its title.

I am doing the following:

```
$id = (int)$wpdb->get_row( "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $current_user->user_login . "' && post_status = 'draft' && post_type = 'post' ", 'ARRAY_N' );

// Update post
  $my_post = array(
      'ID'            => $id,
      'post_title'    => $current_user->user_login,
      'post_content'  => $current_user->user_email,
  );

// Update the post into the database
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

However, the `$id` that I get is `1`, and therefore the post does not get updated. As error I get:

> Invalid post ID.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what post you are trying to get? If you logged in as admin , you are trying to get a post with post_title as admin username , status as draft  and type as post . And you are getting result as 1. ?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman Yes. I would like to get the post id, which has the username in the post titel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $row = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $current_user->user_login . "' && post_status = 'draft' && post_type = 'post' ", 'ARRAY_N');
        if (!empty($row)) {
// Update post
            $my_post = array(
                'ID' => $row[0],
                'post_title' => $current_user->user_login,
                'post_content' => $current_user->user_email,
            );

// Update the post into the database
            wp_update_post($my_post);
        }
```

Try this snippet

Answer (score 1):

use get_var for obtain single value from db  and 'AND' in mysql

```
  $id = (int)$wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts 
         WHERE post_title = '" . $current_user->user_login . "' 
         AND post_status = 'draft' 
         AND  post_type = 'post' ", 'ARRAY_N' );
```